# Filling a view model from entity data, getting convertion error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to fill a `ViewModel` from a LINQ to Entities query but I am getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to GameSEctionVM

and I am not really sure what conversion I am supposed to use. I have seen many examples online where the VM holds multiple versions of the data (say a list of query results) but none where it would represent a single row of data like this. What am I doing wrong?

```
        using (SectionContext db = new SectionContext())
        {
            string RouteName = RouteData.Values["RouteName"].ToString();
            GameSectionVM model = (from s in db.Sections
                                   join f in db.Files on s.LogoFileID equals f.ID
                                   where s.RouteName == RouteName
                                   select new GameSectionVM
                                   {
                                       GameTitle = s.Title,
                                       LogoFileName = f.FileName,
                                       Synopsis = s.Synopsis
                                   });
            return View(model);
        }

public class GameSectionVM
{
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string LogoFileName { get; set; }
    public string Synopsis { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply materialize your query by adding `.FirstOrDefault()` :

```
GameSectionVM model = (from s in db.Sections
                       join f in db.Files on s.LogoFileID equals f.ID
                       where s.RouteName == RouteName
                       select new GameSectionVM
                       {
                           GameTitle = s.Title,
                           LogoFileName = f.FileName,
                           Synopsis = s.Synopsis
                       }).FirstOrDefault();
```

That will convert your linq which was of type `System.Linq.IQueryable` to single `GameSectionVM` object.

Answer (score 0):

Your L2S query does not return a GameSectionVM object.  It returns an unexecuted query, hence the IQueryable.  To actually an object or objects you need to execute the query.  To do that you would call a method like ToArray, ToList, First, Single, FirstOrDefault, SingleOrDefault, Count, etc, or else enumerate the result with a `foreach` loop.  In your case, you seem to be expecting a single object so Single or SingleOrDefault would be appropriate.  If there will always be one object then use Single but if there might not be a match then use SingleOrDefault and test for `null`.